# integer division properties

Tags: algorithm, integer, theory, division

does the following integer arithmetic property hold?

```
(m/n)/l == m/(n*l)
```

At first I thought I knew answer (does not hold), but now am not sure.
Does it hold for all numbers or only for certain conditions, i.e. `n > l`?

the question pertains to computer arithmetic, namely `q = n/m, q*m != n`, ignoring overflow.

Comment: Do you care about edge cases like overflows?  Or wierd architectures/languages like those where `n/m` rounds down instead of toward zero?

Comment: [Is (a/b)/c equal to a/(b*c) for integer division?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2557458/90333)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to replace "a/(b\*c)" with "a/b/c" when using integer-division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45112911/is-it-safe-to-replace-a-bc-with-a-b-c-when-using-integer-division)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Case1 assume m = kn+b (b<n),
left = (m/n)/l = ((kn+b)/n)/l = (k+b/n)/l = k/l (b/n=0, because b<n)
right = (kn+b)/(n*l) = k/l + b/(n*l) = k/l (b/(n*l)=0, because b<n)
=> left = right

Case2 assume m = kn,
left = (m/n)/l = (kn/n)/l = k/l
right = kn/(n*l) = k/l
=> left = right

So, (m/n)/l == m/(n*l)
```

Comment: Not true if n*l overflows the bound of the integer type.

Comment: @mtrw to be fair, that goes without saying

Comment: @ziang, @aaa - I downvoted this thinking that overflow was an important part of the question.  Now my downvote is too old to undo.  Sorry ziang.

Comment: @mtrw, not a problem at all. We learn and discuss things here, who cares about the votes :)

Comment: This is a good answer, but `case2` isn't necessary, it's just a subset of `Case` where`b==0`.

Answer (score 5):

Are you talking about mathematical integers?  Or fixed-width integers within a programming language?

The two equations are identical with mathematical integers, but the two functions have different overflow behaviors if you are using fixed-width integers.

For example, suppose integers are 32-bit

```
(1310720000/65536)/65537 = 20000/65537 = 0
```

However, 65536 * 65537 will overflow a 32-bit integer, and will equal 65536, so

```
1310720000/(65536*65537) = 1310720000/65536 = 20000
```

Comment: +1 for beating me to it.  And if I could, another +1 for apparently being the only responder to catch the word integer!