# In C# integer arithmetic, does a/b/c always equal a/(b*c)?

Tags: c#, math, integer, integer-arithmetic

Let a, b and c be non-large positive integers. Does a/b/c always equal a/(b * c) with C# integer arithmetic?  For me, in C# it looks like:

```
int a = 5126, b = 76, c = 14;
int x1 = a / b / c;
int x2 = a / (b * c);
```

So my question is: does `x1 == x2` for all a, b and c?

Comment: This is a maths question, not a programming one. Can you explain what the programming specific part of this question is?

Comment: @Oded in the scope of any rational number, sure, but this is specifically referring to integer arithmetic (in C#). IMO that makes it programming-related. Maybe the rule that a/b/c == a/(b*c) holds in integer arithmetic, maybe it only holds in rational number arithmetic.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question about C#, and easy to answer.

Comment: @Oded This is a question about computer arithmetic and whether it behaves the same as pure math. It should not be closed.

Comment: Have you done any investigation yourself regarding this?

Comment: I'd be quite interested in a mathematical proof of why (or indeed whether), ignoring overflows, the two are in fact equivalent, but I've not managed to put one together yet.

Comment: @Rawling Well, given the range of an int it wouldn't be too terribly difficult to just brute force the whole thing and actually experimentially verify if every combination either is equal or overflows.

Comment: I've brute forced this for all values from `1` to `10000` for `a`, `b` and `c` and there was no inequality. I also tested by assigning `x1` in two steps: `x1 = a / b; x1 /= c;`, and that made no difference.

Comment: I've persuaded myself that, mathematically, `floor(a/(b*c)) = floor(floor(a/b)/c)`, although I can't phrase it very well. First note that `a/(b*c) = (a/b)/c`. Then if `x = a/b`,  no integer multiple of `c` can possibly lie between `x` and `floor(x)` so `floor(x/c)` and `floor(floor(x)/c)` must be equal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [integer division properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634546/integer-division-properties)

Comment: @BrunoMartinez the proof overthere is really much easier to understand

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Let `\` denote integer division (the C# `/` operator between two `int`s) and let `/` denote usual math division. Then, if `x,y,z` are **positive integers** and we are **ignoring overflow**,

```
(x \ y) \ z
    = floor(floor(x / y) / z)      [1]
    = floor((x / y) / z)           [2]
    = floor(x / (y * z))
    = x \ (y * z)
```

where

```
a \ b = floor(a / b)
```

The jump from line `[1]` to line `[2]` above is explained as follows. Suppose you have two integers `a` and `b` and a fractional number `f` in the range `[0, 1)`. It is straightforward to see that

```
floor(a / b) = floor((a + f) / b)  [3]
```

If in line `[1]` you identify `a = floor(x / y)`, `f = (x / y) - floor(x / y)`, and `b = z`, then `[3]` implies that `[1]` and `[2]` are equal.

You can generalize this proof to negative integers (still **ignoring overflow**), but I'll leave that to the reader to keep the point simple.

---

On the issue of **overflow** - see Eric Lippert's answer for a good explanation! He also takes a much more rigorous approach in [his blog post](http://ericlippert.com/2013/06/04/an-integer-division-identity/) and answer, something you should look into if you feel I'm being too hand-wavy.

Comment: Hah, that's what I was after :)

Comment: I like your use of \ and / for this. Makes things much more clear.

Comment: @JustinMorgan The notation is actually used in some other programming languages (although I don't remember which ones at the moment).

Comment: @TimothyShields VB.net does.

Comment: I think the claim is true, but your proof seems to be missing a key step. It's possible I misunderstood your justification for line 2 => line 3. The way I interpreted it was `floor(x / y) - (x / y)` is small and `z >= 1` so taking the `floor` of that is 0 and we can ignore it. That doesn't actually follow since it's actually an addend within a `floor()` (i.e. consider `floor(1/2)` vs `floor(1/2 + 1/2)`).

Comment: @roliu I'll try to clarify it later when I'm not on my phone.

Comment: @roliu So what I was trying to clarify with those steps in the middle of the proof was that `floor(floor(x / y) / z) = floor((x / y) / z)`. Because the numerator is changing from `floor(x / y)` to `(x / y)` it is increasing *from an integer value* by an amount in `[0, 1)`. But since we're dividing that by an integer `z` and then flooring again, we have the equality. An example would be `floor(9/7) = floor(9.4536345/7)`. The `floor(1/2 + 1/2)` counterexample you mention doesn't fit here because *both* of your addends are fractional. We're guaranteed that one is an integer here.

Comment: @TimothyShields I agree with that argument, but I don't think it's argued convincingly in the way you presented it. In particular, I think that going from `floor(floor(x/y)/z) => floor(x/y/z)` is essentially what you did because the line in the middle doesn't offer any insight into why that's true (`x/y/z` could be fractional and so could `(floor(x/y) - x/y))/z`. I presented a proof below which, in my opinion, clarifies that idea. Dang, I finally checked and it's actually the same argument that Lippert gives. Oh well heh.

Comment: @roliu I updated my answer to (hopefully!) better explain that jump that was bothering you. :)

Comment: @TimothyShields Yep, that's the argument (except you technically need `a < b`). +1

Comment: @roliu You don't need `a < b`. Only an example, but it should convince you: `floor(9 / 2) = 4 = floor((9 + 0.999) / 2)` - This is true because the `0.999` is strictly less than `1`.

Comment: @TimothyShields Ah, I was trying to understand why I was so confused by your original proof. It's because you really want `floor(floor(x/y)/z) = floor(floor(x/y)/z + (x/y - floor(x/y))/z)` which is true by the argument you give above. But you had `floor(x/y/z + (floor(x/y) - x/y)/z) = floor(x/y/z)` which wasn't (isn't?) clear to me.

Comment: @roliu I agree this newer version of that step is clearer. The previous one (though not incorrect) was a little convoluted. :)

Answer (score 76):

I liked this question so much I made it the subject of [my blog on June 4th, 2013](http://ericlippert.com/2013/06/04/an-integer-division-identity/). Thanks for the great question!

---

Large cases are easy to come by. For example:

```
a = 1073741823; 
b = 134217727;
c = 134217727;
```

because `b * c` overflows to a negative number.

I would add to that the fact that in *checked arithmetic*, the difference between `a / (b * c)` and `(a / b) / c` can be the difference between a program that works and a program that crashes. If the product of `b` and `c` overflows the bounds of an integer then the former will crash in a checked context.

For small positive integers, say, small enough to fit into a short, the identity should be maintained.

---

Timothy Shields just posted a proof; I present here an alternative proof. Assume all the numbers here are non-negative integers and none of the operations overflow.

Integer division of `x / y` finds the value `q` such that `q * y + r == x`, where `0 <= r < y`.

So the division `a / (b * c)` finds the value `q1` such that

```
q1 * b * c + r1 == a
```

where `0 <= r1 < b * c`

the division `( a / b ) / c` first finds the value `qt` such that

```
qt * b + r3 == a
```

and then finds the value `q2` such that

```
q2 * c + r2 == qt
```

So substitute that in for `qt` and we get:

```
q2 * b * c + b * r2 + r3 == a
```

where `0 <= r2 < c` and `0 <= r3 < b`.

Two things equal to the same are equal to each other, so we have

```
q1 * b * c + r1 == q2 * b * c + b * r2 + r3
```

Suppose `q1 == q2 + x` for some integer `x`.  Substitute that in and solve for `x`:

```
q2 * b * c + x * b * c + r1 = q2 * b * c + b * r2 + r3
x  = (b * r2 + r3 - r1) / (b * c)
```

where

```
 0 <= r1 < b * c
 0 <= r2 < c
 0 <= r3 < b
```

Can `x` be greater than zero?  No. We have the inequalities:

```
 b * r2 + r3 - r1 <= b * r2 + r3 <= b * (c - 1) + r3 < b * (c - 1) + b == b * c
```

So the numerator of that fraction is always smaller than `b * c`, so `x` cannot be greater than zero.

Can `x` be less than zero?  No, by similar argument, left to the reader.

Therefore integer `x` is zero, and therefore `q1 == q2`.

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos yes, but both the `x1` **and** the `x2` operation will crash identically in that case

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos is that not true of both cases?

Comment: vc 74's answer has been deleted, so most people can no longer see the example you're referencing.

Comment: That's correct, both `x1` and `x2` will crash if `b` or `c` are zero. For other values, the `x1` expression is better, since will avoid the  possible integer overflow of `( b * c)` that `x2` has.

Comment: Interesting point about overflows and checked arithmetic, thanks!

Comment: @JasonCrease: You're welcome; I've posted an alternate proof of the identity as well.

Comment: It's a little bit shorter to show that the remainder `b * r2 + r3` is always between `0` and `b*c`, so that `q1 == q2`: `0 <= b * r2 + r3 <= b * (c - 1) + (b - 1) = b * c - 1`.

Answer (score 4):

If the absolute values of `b` and `c` are below about `sqrt(2^31)` (approx. 46 300), so that `b * c` will never overflow, the values will always match.  If `b * c` overflows, then an error can be thrown in a `checked` context, or you can get an incorrect value in an `unchecked` context.

Answer (score 2):

Avoiding the overflow errors noticed by others, they always match.

Let's suppose that `a/b=q1`, which means that `a=b*q1+r1`, where `0<=r1<b`.
Now suppose that `a/b/c=q2`, which means that `q1=c*q2+r2`, where `0<=r2<c`.
This means that `a=b(c*q2+r2)+r1=b*c*q2+br2+r1`.
In order for `a/(b*c)=a/b/c=q2`, we need to have `0<=b*r2+r1<b*c`.
But `b*r2+r1<b*r2+b=b*(r2+1)<=b*c`, as required, and the two operations match.

This doesn't work if `b` or `c` are negative, but I don't know how integer division works in that case either.

Answer (score 0):

I'll offer my own proof for fun. This also ignores overflow and only handles positives unfortunately, but I think the proof is clean and clear.

The goal is to show that

`floor(floor(x/y)/z) = floor(x/y/z)`

where `/` is normal division (throughout this proof).

We represent the quotient and remainder of `a/b` *uniquely* as `a = kb + r` (by that we mean that `k,r` are unique and also note `|r| < |b|`). Then we have:

```
(1) floor(x/y) = k => x = ky + r
(2) floor(floor(x/y)/r) = k1 => floor(x/y) = k1*z + r1
(3) floor(x/y/z) = k2 => x/y = k2*z + r2
```

So our goal is just to show that `k1 == k2`. Well we have:

```
k1*z + r1 = floor(x/y) = k = (x-r)/y (from lines 1 and 2)
=> x/y - r/y = k1*z + r1 => x/y = k1*z + r1 + r/y
```

and thus:

```
(4) x/y = k1*z + r1 + r/y (from above)
x/y = k2*z + r2 (from line 3)
```

Now observe from (2) that `r1` is an integer (for `k1*z` is an integer by definition) and `r1 < z` (also by definition). Furthermore from (1) we know that `r < y => r/y < 1`. Now consider the sum `r1 + r/y` from (4). The claim is that `r1 + r/y < z` and this is clear from the previous claims (because `0 <= r1 < z` and `r1` is an integer so we have `0 <= r1 <= z-1`. Therefore `0 <= r1 + r/y < z`). Thus `r1 + r/y = r2` by definition of `r2` (otherwise there would be *two* remainders from `x/y` which contradicts the definition of remainder). Hence we have:

```
x/y = k1*z + r2
x/y = k2*z + r2
```

and we have our desired conclusion that `k1 = k2`.

The above proof should work with negatives except for a couple steps that you'd need to check an extra case(s)... but I didn't check.

Answer (score 0):

counter example: INT_MIN / -1 / 2

Comment: "Let a, b and c be non-large **positive** integers."

Comment: That's an interesting case (i.e. -INT_MIN is an overflow). Thanks!