# Associative Property on floating point number additions

Tags: floating-point

Let x, y, and z be floating point numbers. Then is it true that (x+y)+z =/= x+(y+z)? Can someone give me an example? I want x,y, and z be floating point numbers (IEEE representation), not just any real numbers.

Comment: To make such an example, you can use a large number `x`,  and choose `y` and `z` small enough that `x+y` and `x+z` both round down to `x`, but large enough that `x + (y+z)` rounds to `x + eps` where eps is the smallest increment that can be represented on the *scale* of `y` (which is a function of the exponent of `x`, the rounding mode of the floating point unit, and the bit-length of the mantissa on the particular hardware architecture.)

Comment: This question is not exact duplicate because 0.1 cannot be exactly represented as IEEE FP.

Comment: @Ted: The numbers that .1, .2, and .7 round to when converted to IEEE-754 are representable, of course, and it is those values that demonstrate the failure of associativity. The failure occurs entirely within IEEE-754 operations. The initial representation of them with decimal plays no role in the demonstration.

Answer (score 5):

As you phrased the question, it is not generally true. There exist x, y, and z such that `(x+y)+z = x+(y+z)`. But you likely intended to ask whether or not it is always true that `(x+y)+z = x+(y+z)`. It is not always true.

An obvious counterexample is (2<sup>64</sup> + −2<sup>64</sup>) + 1 and 2<sup>64</sup> + (−2<sup>64</sup> + 1). With 64-bit binary IEEE-754 arithmetic, the former is 0 + 1 = 1, and the latter is 2<sup>64</sup> + −2<sup>64</sup> = 0. In the latter, the 1 was lost because the magnitude of −2<sup>64</sup> is so great the sum did not have enough precision to include the 1.

There are more subtle cases, where just a part of one number is lost.

Comment: One of the interesting features of your example is that all three inputs can be represented exactly in 64-bit binary IEEE-754.